# initializing a byte array in Java by its value?

Tags: java, byte

hence i have the bytes value of a String. For example via:

```
String str="Test String";
System.out.println(str.getBytes());
```

which gives me:

```
[B@1339a0dc
```

can i use this for initializing a bytes array such as:

```
byte[] bytes=new bytes("[B@1339a0dc");
```

or something?

Answer (score 2):

`getBytes` returns a `byte` array. So you can do:

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

directly.

`[B@1339a0dc` is just an object reference represented as a String, it is not the actual byte array

Answer (score 1):

No. That's the class name (`[B` is `byte[]`) and the hashcode (`1339a0dc` is the hash code in hexadecimal). Hashes cannot be reversed since they're not [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_function).

Why it prints this? Because you're using an implicit `toString()`. This:

```
System.out.println(str.getBytes());
```

gets translated by the compiler as this:

```
System.out.println(str.getBytes().toString());
```

because `System.out.println()` takes a `String` as argument, so an implicit conversion is made here.

So you're using the default `Object#toString()` implementation, which works as I explained before (more details [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29))